# C# : System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow doesn't return same value on other PC

Tags: c#, wpf, mdi, mdiparent, mainwindow

In Visual Studio 2010, I have an Mdi application build with WPF. When calling Popup windows, I want to set the Owner with the current main window. So, we used the `System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow` property to set the Owner.

That works on all my colleagues PC but not on mine. It always returns the popup windows itself. why??

Comment: Were the two machines cloned from the same windows image, with all software pre-installed? If not, then you need to try to examine the differences between the two machines. For each difference you find, try to find two more machines with that same difference, and see whether this behaviour difference also exists there.

Comment: Why other software installed may intefere with `Current.MainWindow` property? We run exactly the same code in VS2010...

Answer (score 0):

You need access to this window therefore try use Window.GetWindow Method, from System.Windows.Window.